# Close Page on click button press asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my first Page Name: RiskQuery.aspx. From this page on Click the
Link button of Grid View , open another page name, RiskMessage.aspx.
Both pages are under same master Page.

1st Page's Grid View Link button tag below:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="AppID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\RiskMessage.aspx?AppID={0}" Text="Message" target="_blank" />
```

code behind of my RiskMessage.aspx:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string id = null;
    try
    {
        id = Session["cust_id"].ToString();
    }
    catch { }

    if (id != null)
    {
        txtEntryHomeID.Text = id;
    }
    getMasterInfo();
}
```

I successfully opened the 2nd Page and from this page, I update my required
 record. But I want to Close the 2nd page after I update the record on the [Save] button press.

I need help closing the 2nd page.

Comment: the only way i could think woulb be javascript but then i dont think the security on modern browsers will let you do that unless you have opened a window with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if suppose your page was popup u can close by using `window.close()`

here u can use instead of

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

otherwise go back one step of your history by using JavaScript

end of your saving code if it is popup

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "script", "window.close();", true);
```

Comment: I have done successfully by your help. Sorry for delay reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code on `Save` button press:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "close", "<script language=javascript>self.close();</script>");
```

Comment: 2nd page is not close till now